# Does English have an equivalent for pinakalast?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Last from English; final, ultimate, last person to arrive.

pinaka- creates superlatives.

Though pinakalast can be both comparative and superlative.

More final than final

Most ultimate

Comment: "Pinaka"?  Like Shiva Dhanush?

Comment: Last is a superlative. You can't create a comparative or superlative from it.

Answer (score 6):

The ***[very last](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/very+last)***  is an expression commonly used.

Examples:

- He was the very last person to arrive at the meeting.
- This is the very last piece available for sale.